# ¿Cómo ordenar un diccionario cuyas valores también son diccionarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, ordenamiento

Tengo un diccionario cual keys tambien estan diccionarios y me gustaria ordernalo sobre `"perceived_benefit"`. Entonces intenté:

```
sorted([{k:v} for k,v in d.items()], 
...                        key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]["perceived_benefit"],
...                        reverse=True)
```

Pero me devuelve que no conoce el Key `"perceived_benefit"`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in <lambda>
KeyError: 'perceived_benefit'
```

Aqui esta el mio diccionario:

```
d = {'je me sens bien': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'romantique': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'me convient bien': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'féminin': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.03389830508474576}, 'sensuel / sexy': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'nettoyer': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'facile a porter': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'ha ute qualite': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'elegante / sophistiquee': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'jeune / juvenile': {'cl aimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'moderne': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'sucré': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'naturel': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'pour le soir / nuit': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'frais': {'claimed_benefit': 0 , 'perceived_benefit': 0.06779661016949153}, 'doux': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.06779661016949153}, 'lumière': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_b enefit': 0.0}, 'classique': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'chaud': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'audacieux': {'claimed_benef it': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'humide': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'poudreux': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'herbes aromatiques': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'a du caractere': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'sportif': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'aquatique / marine': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'floral': {'claimed_benefit': 1, 'perceived_benefit': 0.03389830508474576}, 'nouveau / jamais respire avant': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'savonneux': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'pour l a journee': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, "n'oublier": {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'vanille': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perce ived_benefit': 0.0}, 'fruité': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'masculin': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'citronné': {'claimed_ benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.01694915254237288}, 'enfumé': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'vert / herbe-like': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perc eived_benefit': 0.0}, 'oriental': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'épicé': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'alimentaire': {'claim ed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'boisé': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Un detalle inicial. No puedes tener un diccionario cuyas claves son diccionarios. Python no lo permite. Sólo los tipos *hasheables*  pueden usarse como clave de diccionario (y éstos tipos son inmutables).

Lo que tienes es un diccionario cuyos *valores* son otros diccionarios. Entiendo que quieres ordenarlos según el valor en su clave "perceived_benefit". El problema es que no todos tus sub-diccionarios tienen esa clave.

Con la siguiente línea podemos ver cuáles son los que no tienen esa clave:

```
[ (k,v) for k,v in d.items() if "perceived_benefit" not in v]
```

Resulta en:

```
[('lumière', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_b enefit': 0.0}),
 ('vanille', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perce ived_benefit': 0.0}),
 ('vert / herbe-like', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perc eived_benefit': 0.0})]
```

Como ves, parece que se trata de erratas, ya que la clave "perceived_benefit" contiene espacios en lugares aleatorios. Deberías limpiar tus datos antes para evitar ese error.

Otra posibilidad es asignarle el valor 0.0 a los elementos que no tengan la clave buscada (en este caso además coincide que 0.0 era su valor). Esto es muy sencillo y con ese truco puedes ordenar sin problemas tu diccionario:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].get("perceived_benefit", 0.0))
```

Así obtienes lo siguiente (abrevio la salida, que es larga):

```
[('je me sens bien', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}),
 ('romantique', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}),
 ('me convient bien', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}),
 # ... omitido ...
 ('féminin', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.03389830508474576}),
 ('floral', {'claimed_benefit': 1, 'perceived_benefit': 0.03389830508474576}),
 ('frais', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.06779661016949153}),
 ('doux', {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.06779661016949153})]
```

Comment: exelente respuesta..